# Change array value and save to database in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, replace

how i can change specific array value in PHP? i have a Movie casts info that is a array:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Mia Wasikowska',
    'id' => 'nm1985859',
    'url' => 'http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1985859/',
    'image' => 'http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTUzNzI0MDczN15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNTQ0MjMxOTE@._V1_.jpg',
    'character' => 'Alice Kingsleigh',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Johnny Depp',
    'id' => 'nm0000136',
    'url' => 'http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000136/',
    'image' => 'http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTM0ODU5Nzk2OV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMzI2ODgyNQ@@._V1_.jpg',
    'character' => 'Hatter Tarrant Hightopp',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Helena Bonham Carter',
    'id' => 'nm0000307',
    'url' => 'http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000307/',
    'image' => 'http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTUzMzUzMDg5MV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMDA5NDMwNA@@._V1_.jpg',
    'character' => 'Iracebeth',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Anne Hathaway',
    'id' => 'nm0004266',
    'url' => 'http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0004266/',
    'image' => 'http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BNjQ5MTAxMDc5OF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwOTI0OTE4OA@@._V1_.jpg',
    'character' => 'Mirana',
  ),
)
```

i need to change image value to something different. for example, change this:

```
'image' => 'http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BNjQ5MTAxMDc5OF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwOTI0OTE4OA@@._V1_.jpg',
```

to this:

```
'image' => '/uploads/images/artirst_0214.jpg',
```

and in the end i need to have it like this:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Mia Wasikowska',
    'id' => 'nm1985859',
    'url' => 'http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1985859/',
    'image' => '/uploads/images/artirst_032.jpg',
    'character' => 'Alice Kingsleigh',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Johnny Depp',
    'id' => 'nm0000136',
    'url' => 'http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000136/',
    'image' => '/uploads/images/artirst_07897.jpg',
    'character' => 'Hatter Tarrant Hightopp',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Helena Bonham Carter',
    'id' => 'nm0000307',
    'url' => 'http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000307/',
    'image' => '/uploads/images/artirst_0987.jpg',
    'character' => 'Iracebeth',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Anne Hathaway',
    'id' => 'nm0004266',
    'url' => 'http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0004266/',
    'image' => '/uploads/images/artirst_0214.jpg',
    'character' => 'Mirana',
  ),
)
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ArrayKeys=array_keys($data);
$cntKeys=count($ArrayKeys);
for ($i=0;$i<$cntKeys;$i++)
{
$data[$ArrayKeys[$i]]["image"]="ciro";
}

print_r ($data);
```

Let's suppose that your array is called "data".
In this way you get can the keys of your array (0,1,2....) and on each of them you iterate to access to the img value...
Then you can access to the value using $data[key_your_array]["image"] = "something". I use

```
$data[$ArrayKeys[$i]]
```

because, as the name suggest, $ArrayKeys is an array and I want to access to the i-th element